# field information lost when importing geojson file into qgis

Tags: qgis, geojson, fields-attributes, import

I have an attribute in the geojson file which contains a list of elements (usually 3). The attribute has 700-1000 characters. I learned that for shape files, qgis can only have fields with less than 255 characters. But I am not sure if it is the same for GeoJson. The strange thing is that, the field is not trancated in qgis, but it is almost empty. It shows something like "(3:,...)".

My questions are first, what is the qgis field character limit strategy for GeoJson, and second, is there a way I can avoid this problem and import the entire attribute into qgis?

Comment: Couold you add a link to a small sample of your GeoJSON? It does not need to contain real data, the structure is important.

Comment: The 255 character limit is a [restriction of the shapefile format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Data_storage), regardless of whether you use QGIS, ArcGIS or another program.